# Why these 2 queued animations have never been executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to the code below, there's a font-size animation inside the first animation's callback function. It should be executed while the first animation is complete. And indeed, the font-size animation is executed after the first animation is finished. Normally, one queued animation should be executed after a certain animation is complete, and the callback function of the previous animation should also be executed at the same time. But in this case, why the 2 queued animations have never been executed?(The queued animations are wholly removed) Is it because of the `.stop(true)` function of the font-size animation? What's the reason? And what's the executive process?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").animate({height: "300px"},3000,"linear",function(){
        $(this).stop(true).animate({fontSize: "50px"},3000,"linear");
    });    //The first animation
    $("div").animate({height: "50px"},3000,"linear");    //The queued animation
    $("div").animate({width: "200px"},3000,"linear");    //The queued animation
});
```

```css
div{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F00;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: add those queued anomations into callback functions

Comment: You’re passing `true` as the first argument to `.stop()`. Here’s the documentation for `.stop()`: https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To queue them in the same style as you are doing for the first animation, you need to pass them in as a callback:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").animate({height: "300px"},3000,"linear",function(){
        $(this).animate({fontSize: "50px"},3000,"linear", function() {
      $("div").animate({height: "50px"},3000,"linear");    //The queued animation
      $("div").animate({width: "200px"},3000,"linear");    //The queued animation    
        });
    });    //The first animation
    
});
```

```css
div{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F00;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add those queued animations inside the callback animation of each animation

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").animate({
    height: "300px"
  }, 3000, "linear", function() {
    $(this).stop(true).animate({
      fontSize: "50px"
    }, 3000, "linear", function() {
      $("div").animate({
        height: "50px"
      }, 3000, "linear", function() {
        $("div").animate({
          width: "200px"
        }, 3000, "linear"); //The queued animation
      }); //The queued animation
    });
  }); //The first animation


});
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F00;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello world!</div>
```